# Definition of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Finally taking the plunge to learn a Lisp dialect (Scheme), I have encountered two definitions of a list -

> "Either the empty list or a pair whose cdr is a list".
>
> "A collection of S-Expressions enclosed by parentheses".

Are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: Read the standard! R5RS, 6.3.2  Pairs and lists: Pairs are used primarily to represent lists. A list can be defined recursively as either the empty list or a pair whose cdr is a list. More precisely, the set of lists is defined as the smallest set X such that ...

Comment: Thanks, this is helping me alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're as equivalent as `{'a','b','c'}` and `"abc"`

The former is the machine's logical representation of a list, the latter is how you represent it in your code.

And in scheme, you can pretty much treat everything as a list :) (Someone's going to downvote me for that, but I found it to be true when trying to think scheme-esque.)

Comment: Actually, you get an upvote for saying that you can treat everything as a list. Because Scheme code actually _is_ a bunch of lists!

Comment: You're exactly right, except that they're not equivalent --- they don't say the same thing.  That said, they _are_ consistent in that they're both true of Scheme lists.

Comment: "you can pretty much treat everything as a list" is a very fuzzy statement and helps not very much. And your string example is a bad one. It  is suited for Haskell not Scheme.

Comment: I do find it to be a fuzzy statement, that's why I qualified it to simply be my personal experience. I.e. "When I started considering everything in Scheme to be a list, it got easier." So did drawing lots of boxes!! :) And with regards to the String example, it simply to illustrate that one is more akin to how the compiler/interpreter sees it as opposed to how we do it with shorthand in code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to bring out my favourite dog-and-pony show!

[image: Tree of cons cells]
<sub>(source: [hedgee.com](http://cloud9.hedgee.com/priv/expr1.png))</sub>

This corresponds to the following:

```
(let ((s5 (sqrt 5)))
  (/ (- (expt (/ (1+ s5) 2) n)
        (expt (/ (- 1 s5) 2) n)) s5))
```

The diagram illustrates your first statement (the empty-list object is denoted as a black box). The code snippet illustrates your second. :-)

Comment: +1 for boxes, because boxes make scheme very, very easy. I killed more trees with graph paper working on scheme than I care to admit!